# Obtain IP and then change last octet

Tags: vbscript

I have a requirement to obtain a PC's IP address via VBS which I am doing using the below:

```
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE MACAddress > ''"

Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://./root/CIMV2" )
Set colItems      = objWMIService.ExecQuery( strQuery, "WQL", 48 )

For Each objItem In colItems
    If IsArray( objItem.IPAddress ) Then
        If UBound( objItem.IPAddress ) = 0 Then
            strIP = "IP Address: " & objItem.IPAddress(0)
        Else
            strIP = "IP Addresses: " & Join( objItem.IPAddress, "," )
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I am then using the below to map a network drive:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork 
Dim strDriveLetter, strRemotePath, strUser, strPassword, strProfile

strDriveLetter = "Z:" 
strRemotePath = "\\10.121.34.140\c$" 
strUser = "user"
strPassword = "Password"
strProfile = "false"

Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath, _
strProfile, strUser, strPassword
```

What I wish to do however is obtain the the IP of the hostmachine (so `10.121.34.130`) and change just the octet to `.140` and map to that.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InStrRev()` and `Left()` functions should be all you need.

```
' Sample starting address...
strIP = "10.121.34.130"

' Get the index of the last period...
i = InStrRev(strIP, ".")

' Append the new last octet starting there...
strIP = Left(strIP, i) & "140"
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
strIP = Left(strIP, InStrRev(strIP, ".")) & "140"
```

Or, as a one-liner that creates your full remote path:

```
strIP = "\\" & Left(strIP, InStrRev(strIP, ".")) & "140\c$"
```

Comment: Perfect - I adjust it so strIP was MyIPAddress and it works a treat - many thanks!!